# fill non-null specific values with previous value in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have table containing 3 columns name, date and flag

| name | date | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 2023-07-10 | 1 |
| one | 2023-07-11 | 408 |
| One | 2023-07-12 | 408 |
| two | 2023-07-10 | 0 |
| two | 2023-07-11 | 0 |
| two | 2023-07-12 | 408 |

WRT to name column, flag =408 must be filled with previous values

| name | date | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 2023-07-10 | 1 |
| one | 2023-07-11 | 1 |
| One | 2023-07-12 | 1 |
| two | 2023-07-10 | 0 |
| two | 2023-07-11 | 0 |
| two | 2023-07-12 | 0 |

help me with Redshift query to do the same

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? (Remove the unrelated dbms tags.)

Comment: Try `LAST_VALUE(NULLIF(flag, 408)) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date)`.

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL unfortunately the `IGNORE NULLS` for the `last_value` is [not implemented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)

> The SQL standard defines a RESPECT NULLS or IGNORE NULLS option for lead, lag, first_value, last_value, and nth_value.
> This is not implemented in PostgreSQL: the behavior is always the same as the standard's default, namely RESPECT NULLS.

So you must make a two step workaround.

In the **first step** you define a grouping column `grp` binding the filled and `null` flag rows together

```
select "name", dt, 
case when flag != 408 then flag end as flag,
sum(case when flag != 408 then 1 end)  
over (partition by name order by dt ) as grp
from tab;

name|dt        |flag|grp|
----+----------+----+---+
one |2023-01-10|   1|  1|
one |2023-01-11|    |  1|
one |2023-01-12|    |  1|
two |2023-01-10|   0|  1|
two |2023-01-11|   0|  2|
two |2023-01-12|    |  2|
```

In the **second step** you take the `first_value` *partition by*  the `nam  **and**` grp` - i.e. you get the *first - filled value.

```
with grp as ( 
select "name", dt, 
case when flag != 408 then flag end as flag,
sum(case when flag != 408 then 1 end)  
over (partition by name order by dt ) as grp
from tab
)
select "name", dt, 
first_value(flag)  
over (partition by name, grp order by dt) as flag
from grp
order by name, dt;

name|dt        |flag|
----+----------+----+
one |2023-01-10|   1|
one |2023-01-11|   1|
one |2023-01-12|   1|
two |2023-01-10|   0|
two |2023-01-11|   0|
two |2023-01-12|   0|
```

Comment: OP explicitly tells in subject that he uses RedShift..

Comment: Sorry @Akina answering questions tagged with `postgresql`;)